# How to click on table row and open another table below table to show DB query result as content using JQuery and JS or Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a table with dynamic content coming from an Oracle Database, based on each row there is suppose to be another information coming from the Database on click event i.e. click on row with ID 1 and this executes an Ajax call with an query condition including the ID 1 than response should be shown in another table below the "basic" table.

I think i have to use something like:

```
$('.table > tbody > tr').click(function() {
    // row was clicked
});
```

But i am not sure, since I want to use a PHP call to the DB, but the UX should be instantaneously like an Ajax action without loading the entire page.

The question:

1. How do I a make the table row clickable (possibly with that JS?)?
2. How do I parse the value from the row as condition as database call?
   Ajax/PHP?
3. How do I handover the values into the second table?

Below is my code so far:

```js
function show(nr) {
    document.getElementById("table1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table3").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table4").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table"+nr).style.display="block";
}
```

```css
#table1, #table2, #table3, #table4 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th onclick='show(1);'>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Peter Pan</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Julia Spencer</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div id="table1">
<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Peter Pan</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Julia Spencer</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```